# Created a folder structure using Automator. I need to update the folder names before it's generated

Tags: automator

I've recently created an application using Automator on my Mac to generate a specific folder structure. The application works perfectly in creating the structure, but I'm facing a challenge with renaming the folders within it.

Currently, all the folders are labeled as "xx," and what I aim to do is to replace "xx" with the name of the top-level folder. I've attached some images below to provide a clearer understanding of my setup.

[image]
[image]
[image]

As shown in the images, I'm wondering if there's a way to automate the renaming process within Automator itself or if there's a script or additional action I could integrate into my workflow to achieve this.

If you examine the folder structure, the initial "xx" should be substituted with the name of the top-level folder, which is "Test2024."
NOTE: The project name will vary with each use case. Therefore, I need an application that can dynamically create the folder structure for any project name provided.

Any help or guidance on how to accomplish this renaming task would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are already using the project name argument when creating the folder structure, is there an issue with just using that?

Comment: I neglected to mention that the project name will vary with each use case. Therefore, I need an application that can dynamically create the folder structure for any project name provided.

Comment: You are already doing that when asking for the project name, which is getting passed to the shell script.

Comment: @red_menace I think my issue is it's not replacing the xx when I run it. Maybe I am missing something? I am not sure to be honest. Thank you

Comment: The `xx` is not being replaced because you are not doing anything to replace it.  The `$2` argument is being used for the base folder name, which you are wanting to use elsewhere, so why not use it elsewhere, such as in place of the `xx`?

Comment: @red_menace Thank you!!! That worked :)